Using lowdb in NextJs + Typescript
I'm trying to get data from my database and I'm using lowDB for read and save to the json file, but when I try to read from the file, my db keep returning empty object, I can't read the file. DataWrapper.tsx code is an wrapper to take out the data and then pass it to ContextWrapper.tsx
Here my code DataWrapper.tsx:


import { JSONFilePreset } from "lowdb/node";
import ContextWrapper from "./ContextWrapper";
import React from 'react'

export interface DB { *intefaced* }
export interface Category { *intefaced* }
export interface Article { *intefaced* }
export interface Properties { *intefaced* }
export const defaultData: DB = *json file structure*




export default async function DataWrapper({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  // read from file using lowDB
  const db = await JSONFilePreset<DB>('./DB/db.json', defaultData);

  //log empty object :(
  console.log(db.data);
  
  return (
    <ContextWrapper data={defaultData}>
      {children}
    </ContextWrapper>
  )
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



and here snapshot of my project's dir:

I would love to get any kind of help :)
